# How do I autojoin my users table with roles table

Tags: java, hibernate

My users table is as following:

```
emp_user table
--------------
id (bigint) PK
uuid (character varying) unique
username (character varying) unique
-- no foreign keys are defined in the table
```

The `UserEntity` class is as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp_user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    private String uuid; // Because of Keycloak internals
    
    @Column(name = "\"user\"")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long identifier;
    
    @OneToMany
    JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "emp_user_id")
    private List<Roles> rolesList;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

A user can has many roles.

```
emp_user_roles table
--------------------
emp_user_id (bigint)
emp_user_role (character varying)
-- both emp_user_id and emp_user_role together is a key
-- no foreign keys are defined in the table
```

The `Roles` class is as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp_user_roles")
public class Roles implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_user_id")
    private Long userId;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_user_role")
    private String userRole;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

I get a result, one user, with rolesList but inside of it there are no roles but only an error message saying `Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception.`

I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have solved the issue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp_user")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable { // <-- must implement Serializable
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "\"user\"")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long identifier;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // <-- both name and referencedColumnName are required
    private List<Roles> rolesList;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You have the same name twice `rolesList`. Hibernate is not so simple and you can have a lot of issues with such mappings.

Comment: @v.ladynev I have forgotten to remove it from the text above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `many-to-many` association because a `Role` can have multiple users. Hibernate will create a join table in such case.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

You can create an additional entity `UserRoleMapping` with `@ManyToOne` to `User` and `@ManyToOne` to `Role`. It will be simply to add or delete `Role`. You will not need to get all roles list to remove one of them. Also you can add unique constraint `(User, Role)` to the `UserRoleMapping`.